# Subset json based on string list of indices using jq

Tags: arrays, json, slice, jq

I have a JSON array that looks like:

```
["a","b","c"]
```

And I have a bash variable which is list of array indices that I would like to subset to

```
ix="0,2"
```

I would like to use `jq` to subset to those indices, yielding the following array:

```
["a", "c"]
```

So far I've been able to parse `$ix` into an array:

```
echo '["a","b","c"]' | jq --arg ix $ix '$ix | split(",") | map(tonumber)'
```

But when I try to use this array of indices to subset `["a","b","c"]`, I have problems (None of the following work):

```
echo '["a","b","c"]' | jq --arg ix $ix '. | $ix | split(",") | map(tonumber)'

echo '["a","b","c"]' | jq --arg ix $ix '. | ($ix | split(",") | map(tonumber))'

echo '["a","b","c"]' | jq --arg ix $ix '. | [$ix | split(",") | map(tonumber)]'

echo '["a","b","c"]' | jq --arg ix $ix '. | .[$ix | split(",") | map(tonumber)]'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do

```bash
jq --arg ix "$ix" '
    ($ix | split(",") | map(tonumber)) as [$a, $b] 
    | .[$a:$b+1]
'
```

The `+1` is needed because the array slice operation `.[from;to]` is from (inclusive) and to (exclusive)

---

The variable-assignment expression `... | exp as $var | ...` uses the input value in the expression, sets the variable, then passes the original input as its output.

---

Another way to do this: split the ix in bash, and pass the values as positional arguments:

```bash
IFS=, read -ra ixs <<< "$ix"
echo '["a","b","c"]' \
| jq --jsonargs '.[$ARGS.positional[0]:$ARGS.positional[1]+1]' "${ixs[@]}"
```

---

So, you have a huge array and a large list of indices to extract? Then perhaps:

```
. as $some_huge_array |
reduce ($ix | split(",") | map(tonumber))[] as $i ([]; . + [$some_huge_array[$i]])
```

---

Rolling up some of these ideas:

```bash
ix="0,3,4"
jq --argjson ixs "[$ix]" '. as $a | reduce $ixs[] as $i ([]; . + [$a[$i]])' <<END_INPUT
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
END_INPUT
```

```json
[
  1,
  4,
  5
]
```

And as @oguzismail points out, `reduce` is not needed here

```bash
jq --argjson ixs "[$ix]" '[.[$ixs[]]]'
```

- `$ixs` is an *array*
- `$ixs[]` is a *stream* of values
- `.[ $ixs[] ]` will output the values of the input array *for each value of $ixs*, as a stream of values

  - this is an **implicit** iteration
- `[ .[$ixs[]] ]` *collects* the previous stream into an array.

Comment: Thanks glenn jackman, unfortunately I just wrote up a toy example for SO.  In my real use case, and the variable `$ix` has thousands of indices.  Is there a solution that doesnt involve assigning a variable to each individual index?

Comment: @AmadouKone The example shown by glenn is the right approach, if you are passing a shell variable to `jq`. A better alternate would be to pass the indices as a JSON e.g. `[0, 1, 2]` using `--argjson` flag which can then be directly used in the jq filter

Comment: That can be done simply with `--argjson ixs "[$ix]"` -- demo `jq -n --argjson ixs "[$ix]" '$ixs'`

Comment: You don't need reduce there. `[.[$ixs[]]]` will do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat test.json
>> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ]

$ ix="0,2"

$ jq --arg ix "$ix" '($ix | split(",") | map(tonumber)) as [$a, $b] | .[$a:$b+1]' test.json

>> [
>>   "a",
>>   "b",
>>   "c"
>> ]


$ jq --arg ix "$ix" '($ix | split(",") | map(tonumber)) as [$a, $b] | .[$a,$b+1]' test.json

>> "a"

>> "d"
```

Note how the output differs between `[$a:$b+1]` and `[$a,$b+1]`.

`[$a:$b+1]` is array slicing which generates a sub-array
whereas
`[$a,$b+1]` selects two individual elements of the original array.